Why does the file size increase after updating form content with PDFBox?
I'm using embedded font subsets. Even when the content before and after modifying a form is consistent, the new file size is still larger than the original file?


As shown in the code above, when I continue to generate 'c' based on 'b', the size of 'c' will be larger than 'b'.
@Test
public void updatePdf() {
    try {
        PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File("/Users/sunyangyang/Desktop/a.pdf"));
        PDAcroForm form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        PDResources defaultResources = form.getDefaultResources();

        File fontFile = new File("/Users/sunyangyang/Desktop/MicrosoftYaHei.ttf");
        PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, new TTFParser().parseEmbedded(new FileInputStream(fontFile)), true);

        defaultResources.put(COSName.HELV, font);
        defaultResources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helve"), font);

        PDTextField field = (PDTextField) form.getField("goods_name");
        if (field != null) {
            String value = "大米";
            field.setValue(value);

            for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                font.addToSubset(field.getValue().charAt(i));
            }
        }
        font.subset();

        document.save("/Users/sunyangyang/Desktop/b.pdf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

I hope that when the content I change does not vary, the file size should not increase.

please add code as text in a code block (between ``` marks), not as an image.

I did as you said.
